# maven3 main resources vs test resources

Tags: maven, maven-3

"src/main/resources" vs "src/test/resources"

Do "src/main/resources" get copied to the classpath for tests or only "src/test/resources"? What is the best method to make my main resources also my test resources? Would like to avoid having duplicate config files sitting around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. When you execute the `mvn clean test`, all java classes, test classes, main resources and test resources are generated/copied to the `${basedir}/target/classes`  and `${basedir}/target/test-classes`. They are available on the classpath.

Normally the `src/main/resources` is a static which will be packed to our artifact. Anyhow they are some use cases that allow the actor to define their resources against our artifact. The `src/test/resources` comes to ensure this during the unit testing.

Not only this, but also, we can define any specific for unit testing at `src/test/resources`, e.g. arquillian configuration for javaee unit testing.

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

as a note, if you have a `build/resources/*` section of your pom which manually includes stuff, having that might mean the default src/main/resources are no longer included (i.e. by specifying something, you've lost the default).

So add this in also seemed to fix it:

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
```